# iptables port forwarding doesn't persist after restart

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, iptables

I have server instance running on amazon ec2. I want to forward from port 80 to 8080 using iptables. Which works fine until restart when it stops forwarding. I have used

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080
```

to set up fowarding. What do I need to do to make it persistant?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a good blog post explaining how to do it
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: You can use the `iptables-save` command

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your firewall rules at boot time.